# Windows credential provider - how to unlock a specific user

Tags: windows, credential-providers, credential-manager

I have been playing with windows 8 credential provider to provider an alternate login mechanism for windows user. It all works fine, however, I'm trying out one specific scenario in case of multiple user accounts on the system.

If a system has 2 users (e.g. A and B) and user A locks the screen. Then is it possible to unlock user B instead of A? By default it tries to unlock the user who locks the computer which is user A in this case. I did some experiments but nothing worked. Is there any documentation explaining if it is feasible or not?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Yes, both A and B are logged in.

Comment: Probably doesn't matter, come to think of it. :-)  If you were using the GUI, you'd have to "switch user" and then log in again, so you probably need the credential provider to initiate a logon - I believe that is possible?

Comment: @HarryJohnston That's exactly what I have been trying to do :) It should be possible though.

Comment: If you manually "switch user" (so as to return to the logon screen) does it then work?

Comment: @HarryJohnston of course. I'm just trying to do it programmatically in my customized credential provider.

Comment: OK, so the problem is how to shift from the unlock screen to the logon screen.  I assume you've tried the CredentialsChanged method?

Comment: @HarryJohnston Right. I used credentialschanged() method but it launches the last logged in user only. I need to launch login screen for another user on that system.

Comment: I can't say that I see anything else to suggest, the API looks fairly limited.  And not many people use it, so I fear you're unlikely to find anyone with experience on SO, but keep the question open by all means - you never know your luck!  It might be worth trying the pGINA mailing list as well though, make contact with people who have actually used that API.  You could cheat, of course; your credential manager is running in the context of the logon UI, so you can send window messages or inject keystrokes.  That's not a good solution, but might be better than nothing.

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33441690/886887)