# Windows 7 Credential Provider (samples) Lock and UNlock

Tags: windows

I've been trying out the examples provided by microsoft
SampleCredentialProvider

as a test i've compiled one of them and registered the dll.   The logon screen now displays two additional tiles, "Administrator" and "Guest",   Clicking on Administrator and providing a valid password allows me to login without issues,

however once I lock the screen and then do unlock,  I re-enter the password but I get "Logon failure:  unknown user name or bad password".

Has anyone come across such issues?

Could it be that the computers are part of domain?

Answer (score 1):

Answered :  I was using a beta version of the samples,  always ensure you download the latest version

Changes include
•   Fixing unlock.  Post-Beta2, Windows Vista changed to require a KerbWorkstationUnlockLogon message type to unlock the machine and a KerbInteractiveLogon message type to log on to the machine.  Previously it would accept a KerbInteractiveLogon message type for both logon and unlock.  The samples have been updated accordingly. [v3.0]